# Is there anyway to influence the outfits my villagers wear?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf

My villagers have terrible taste in clothing. They've all been wearing the same ugly camouflage shirt for about a week now. When a villager moves into town they quickly get caught up in the crazy and will swap into the same ugly shirt. I know that if I put up patterns in the Able Sisters that my villagers might wear them, and I put up a design a few days ago hoping they'd start to switch to it, but it didn't work. They're still wearing that same ugly shirt.

Is there anything I can do to influence my villagers to change their outfits, or will I just need to wait until the  ugly shirt fashion craze is over?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Talk to Isabelle at the counter in the Town Hall and choose "problematic citizens."  This will allow you to choose the neighbor, then give you some options.  The options are:

"His/her language is rude."  This resets their greeting and catchphrase.

"His/her clothes are wrong." This randomly changes their clothes.

"He/she has a naughty letter."  I'm not sure what this option does.  Deletes the letter I guess.

Also, when you put things up for sale at Re-Tail, your neighbors will occasionally come in to the shop when you're there.  They will randomly select an item which will be announced by the alert sound and surprise lines over their head.  You can influence them to purchase what they're looking at.  If you have clothes in Re-Tail, that's another possible way for them to change their clothes.

Comment: To clarify the "naughty letter" part, visiting players are able to send your letters to your neighbours after interacting with them at least once.

Occasionally, these neighbours may show you these letters. The above option is primarily used to dispose of rude letters send this way.

Answer (score 3):

You can send them the clothes via letters by attaching them as gifts.It works about a fifth of the time and it seem that it helps to match the theme of the clothing to their personality type (e.g. basketball shirt for a sporty villager or cute for a peppy villager). If they don't accept the clothing it'll go into their house as furniture. Hope I helped!

Answer (score 2):

You can put on sale certain clothes you want them to use or develop a new fashion trend by creating/using custom designs. The villagers may go to a shop and get what you wanted but it will take some time for them to try a new outfit.

If you talk with them, eventually you could get a "What do you think of my style?" conversation (this seems to be purely random). I believe that disapproving their outfit will encourage them to change them but, even after this, it will take a while for them to do it.

Comment: I tried gifting a shirt as Ben Brocka suggested but, so far, nothing has happened. I'm hoping is just a matter of time.

Comment: It worked! The next day after the delivery, the villager was using the shirt I mailed to him.

Answer (score 0):

If you add custom designs to the Able Sisters' store your villagers will occasionally pick the design. From my experience in previous games they seem more willing to wear user-made designs on display than the default displayed designs. These designs (and other clothes) may spread virally as one villager talks to another.

Occasionally villagers will ask for new clothes as a random quest, or receive clothes from another villager (you can't control when this happens). These are random events though and you can only find them by repeatedly talking to the villagers.

Comment: Pure speculation, I wonder if you mail a shirt as a present if the recipient will wear that? I'll try that out